# Cannot Install nor remove from ubuntu 16.04.7

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, python3

After running a latest update and upgrade the PC doesn't allow to install nor update giving me error

```
[sudo] password for velukutty: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gettext is already the newest version (0.19.7-2ubuntu3.1).

The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
Suggested packages:
  python3-launchpadlib

The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk

5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/168 kB of archives.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 255140 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.96.20.10_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.96.20.10_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-gtk_0.96.20.10_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-gtk_0.96.20.10_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.96.20.10_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-software-properties_0.96.20.10_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 26, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 89, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext, ngettext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.24_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.96.20.10_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-gtk_0.96.20.10_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-software-properties_0.96.20.10_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried rebooting and tried `sudo apt-get autoclean`,`sudo apt-get --fix missing`,`sudo apt-get --fix-broken`,`sudo apt-get autoremove`,`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`,but these commands give the same result

So is there a solution other than reinstalling ubuntu ?

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?

Comment: Rebooting is the first thing that i did before posting

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install gettext`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema i have update the question code after running the cmds you have mentioned

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for late reply but it gives me Input/output error                                                    Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** (scrollable) window.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your prompt replies and sry for the trouble the hdd died yesterday and i getting a new one